# Ignore blank cells after using Filter in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

My Table looks like this
[image]

This is a result of using
=filter('Form Responses 1'!A:BJ,'Form Responses 1'!F:F=subjects!A19)

Now all I have to do is, ignore the blank cells and put in the last 3 columns.

I mean, columns N,O,P should come to H,I,J and similiarly other columns towards right of column G should come to columns to H,I,J.

Please help

Comment: Please be specific what is your expected output. Column Letters are not shown in the screenshot. Where do you want to filter from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER({'Form Responses 1'!A:G, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!H:BJ="",,'Form Responses 1'!H:BJ&"♥")),,9^9)), "♥"))}, 
 'Form Responses 1'!F:F=subjects!A19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `A4` to:

```
=filter('Form Responses 1'!A:G,'Form Responses 1'!F:F=subjects!A19)
```

Put this to `H4`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(filter('Form Responses 1'!H:BJ,'Form Responses 1'!F:F=subjects!A19)&"♦"),,ROWS(A4:A))),"^(♦ )+|(♦ )*♦$|(♦ )(♦ )+","$4"),"♦ ",FALSE),))
```

Sample:
[image]